# Recyclerview store and restore

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am creating simple recyclerview for a while. I would like to create recyclerview that gets data from Activity B, and Activity B passes the input data into recyclerview in Activity A (which is mainactivity). I pass the data with registerForActivityResult. passing data works, but everytime I turn into Activity B to upload new recyclerview, previously created recyclerview is gone and new recyclerview is created. I want the recyclerview to be stacked, is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You are running in bad logical error! Please better explains your need